# Kubernetes multi cluster dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

I need to manage a federation of clusters (KubeFed), so I was wondering if it's possible to deploy Lens Dashboard within the cluster?
Otherwise is there any alternative dashboad with multi cluster support within cluster?